# how to write a CSS rule that only applies if position:fixed is not supported or Jquery-test for position:fixed?

Tags: jquery, position, css

I have two CSS files and I can only edit the 2nd file.

My HTML element:

```
<div class="ui-header ui-header-fixed"></div>
```

First CSS file sets:

```
.ui-header        { position: relative };
.ui-header-fixed  { position: fixed };
```

So when *position:fixed* is not supported, the CSS falls back to *position:relative*. However, I need it to fallback to **position:absolute** in this specific case only.

I'm looking for a way to override the above CSS from the 2nd file with *position:absolute*, but **only** if *position:fixed* is not supported.

**Question:**
Is this possible at all? I can't use Jquery to change the CSS directly, but if there is a JQuery test for position:fixed being supported, that would be useable (set a class add a CSS rule)

Comment: The only browser that doesn't support `position: fixed` is Opera mini? http://caniuse.com/css-fixed

Comment: Ok. Found this: http://kangax.github.com/cft/#IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you edit the element? In your second stylesheet (assuming it is listed second in the head), add

```
.ui-header-abs        { position: absolute };
```

and change the element itself to

```
<div class="ui-header ui-header-abs"></div>
```

---

Failing that: If you mean for one document only, and you can edit its `<head>` element, you might want to try inserting

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-header        { position: absolute }
.ui-header-fixed  { position: fixed }
</style>
```

I'm fairly sure you don't actually need the second rule, actually. The precedence rules still trip me up sometimes, but IIRC a style element in the document overrides an external stylesheet (for the same selector), so this should override the two rules in that first (uneditable) stylesheet.

If you can't get that style element into the header, it will probably work in the body element, but that's not valid.

---

I'd need to play with it, but this should be solvable without DOM trickery using plain old CSS and its precedence rules; I don't understand why there's a need to complicate matters with jQuery in this case.

Comment: In the days of Netscape 4 (so before CSS was really usable), I once spent four hours bashing out Javascript to try and centre an element before I remembered the old <center> tag... Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 0):

you can attract css-rules with jQuery, like this:

```
var position = $("MyElement").css("position");
```

I'm not really sure about this, but this should return the css value of `position`.

Comment: true, lets see if I can setup something with this.

Comment: you can set CSS-rules with `$("MyElement").css("position:fixed");` @frequent hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have found a nice solution using this:

```
http://kangax.github.com/cft/#IS_POSITION_FIXED_SUPPORTED
```

To detect, whether position:fixed is supported. If it's not, I'm adding a class of `noFix` to the html element and then write my CSS rules in the 2nd file like so:

```
   .noFix .ui-header { positon: absolute; }
```

Since this rule is in the 2nd file, it overwrites the first `position:relative` only if position fixed is not supported.

Comment: That's another way of doing it... but standard CSS is the way to go here. Plenty of ways to skin this particular cat without resorting to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is rather old, here's another approach that addresses the question more expressively. (and possibly wasn't available at that time)

```
.ui-header-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    @supports not (position:fixed) {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain in you answer why yours is better/an improvement to the existing answers.